# How to assign a random id to a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am working on a project and it is a guessing game. I want the order of the buttons to be random so that the correct answer wont always be the left one, for example. So my HTML buttons ids are "1", "2", "3", "4" and i want to assign each of them a random id (ex. 1 becomes 4) bI have already tried to do math.random and make it 1-4 there is a chance of overlapping numbers. How can i make it so the numbers don't overlap? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that it would be better not to create or search for new random number. But shuffle your existing array. And than assign ids to the buttons.

```js
var ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
var shuffledIds = shuffle(ids);
console.log(shuffledIds);

function shuffle(array) {
    var rand, index = -1,
        length = array.length,
        result = Array(length);
    while (++index < length) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
        result[index] = result[rand];
        result[rand] = array[index];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of your buttons IDs (we'll use 1 - 4 here), then grab a random element from the array and use that as your button ID.

The `while` loop goes through the array of button IDs and pulls one out at random, and removes it from the array so it can't be selected again. It repeats this process until the array of button IDs is empty.

```js
var buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4];

while (buttons.length) {
  var buttonEl = document.createElement('button');
  var buttonId = buttons.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * buttons.length), 1)[0];
  buttonEl.id = 'id-' + buttonId;
  buttonEl.innerText = buttonId;

  document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(buttonEl);
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
</div>
```